# Remove trailing zeros for exponential numbers using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, scientific-notation

Using regular expression, how can I remove the trailing zeros for 1.0000000000e+12?

For example:

- 1.0000000000e+12 should result: 1e+12
- 1.0000000000e12 should result: 1e12
- 1.0000000000e-12 should result: 1e-12
- 1.1200000000e+12 should result: 1.12e+12
- 994.44 should result: 994.44

Comment: Those are not leading zeros, they're trailing zeros.

Answer (score 2):

This is a somewhat difficult problem, as you must ensure there's a decimal point in the number to only eliminate non significative zeroes in it  (zeroes are significiant on the left part of the decimal point).  You must conserve also the significative digits *after* de decimal point and eliminate only the final zeroes.  Also, not all floating point numbers are terminated with a base exponential factor,  this is my approach:

```
str.replace(/\.([0-9]*[1-9])?0*/g, ".$1");
```

Sorry, but it doesn't eliminate the decimal dot, as you can have valid digits after it.

See [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fW0eY2/3)

### Update

If you want to remove optionally also the dot, you can use the next regexp and pattern substitution:

```
str.replace(/(\.[0-9]*[1-9])0*|(\.0*)/, "$1");
```

See [Regexp Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fW0eY2/4)

```js
function removeZeroes(number) {
  return number.replace(/(\.[0-9]*[1-9])0*|(\.0*)/, "$1");
}

document.write(removeZeroes('1.000000000e12') + '<br />');
document.write(removeZeroes('1.000000000e-12') + '<br />');
document.write(removeZeroes('1.000000000E-12') + '<br />');
document.write(removeZeroes('1.001200000e-12') + '<br />');
document.write(removeZeroes('1.120000000e+12') + '<br />');
document.write(removeZeroes('10.120000000e+12') + '<br />');
document.write(removeZeroes('10e12') + '<br />');
document.write(removeZeroes('994.44') + '<br />');
document.write(removeZeroes('994.4400000000') + '<br />');
document.write(removeZeroes('100000000.000') + '<br />');
document.write(removeZeroes('10000000.0') + '<br />');
document.write(removeZeroes('123.00000001230000') + '<br />');
```

Comment: @anubhava, thanks.  I supposed you had not seen it, as by your comment.  Thanks for the upvoting.

Comment: @LuisColorado: Hope you don't mind...I added a code snippet to your solution providing a combination of my test cases and yours. Your solution seems to pass all tests. Great job! +1

Comment: fine, but it doesn't add too much to the solution, as it has already demostrated with the regexp demos.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Number.toExponential`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential).

You can specify the number of digits after the decimal point, but if omitted, it defaults to as many digits as necessary to specify the number.

The only things it doesn't do that you say you want are (1) will always put a `+` before the exponent, and (2) will not work with numbers that you don't want to be in exponential format.

```
INPUT            OUTPUT
1.0000000000e+12 1e+12
1.0000000000e12  1e+12
1.0000000000e-12 1e-12
1.1200000000e+12 1.12e+12
994.44           9.9444e+2
```

To adapt it more closely to your needs, you could write a little wrapper.

When you say you want `1.0000000000e12` to become `1e12`, I assume you realize that in JS there is no difference between the notations `1.0000000000e12` and `1.0000000000e+12`. Numbers specified in either format mean the same thing, and once parsed by the interpreter there is no way to recover whether a `+` was originally specified or not. So I suppose you are getting these numbers as strings from somewhere, where the presence or the absence of the `+` can be detected? If that is the case, you could check on input whether the `+` is there, and if not, remove it from the result of `Number.toExponential`.

To handle the case `994.44`, you could either set up a check to apply `Number.toExponential` only to numbers over a certain threshold; or, again if the number is coming in as a string, you could detect the presence or absence of the exponent and, if absent, skip the call to `Number.toExponential`.